# HTML Dropdown with separate select menu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle a basic select dropdown, but with a toggle that is separate/has a slight gap from the options.
Like so:

[image]

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tbuchanan/bzh2g6o7/2/) and my form code:

```
<form method="post">
<label for="month">Choose Month
    <br>
        <span class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--silver">
            <select id="month" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--silver">
                <option>JAN</option>
                <option>FEB</option>
                <option>MAR</option>
                <option>APR</option>
                <option>MAY</option>
                <option>JUN</option>
                <option>JUL</option>
                <option>AUG</option>
                <option>SEP</option>
                <option>OCT</option>
                <option>NOV</option>
                <option>DEC</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        </label>
    </form>
```

I'm not sure how to continue to toggle the options after the arrow has been moved outside of the select element's clickbable area. Please help.

Comment: It's not possible to open the select from outside. You'd have to use something like Bootstraps's dropdowns: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: @Reeno I'll check that out. Thank you.

Comment: It's also not going to be possible to interact with pseudo-content (aka the `::before` drop-down arrow. So if you want people to be able to click an element, make it a real element, not a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a bit of a workaround but if you wrap the span in a div and apply a click event to that you can make it seem like the arrow has been clicked. And you also need to stop the actual select click from bubbling up.

http://jsfiddle.net/bzh2g6o7/7/

JS:

```
document.getElementById('month').addEventListener('click',
    function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
);

document.getElementById('divWrap').addEventListener('click',
    function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var dropdown = document.getElementById('month');
        var newEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        newEvent.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
        dropdown.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<label for="month">Choose Month
    <br>
        <div id="divWrap">
        <span class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--silver">
            <select id="month" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--silver">
            <option>JAN</option>
            <option>FEB</option>
            <option>MAR</option>
            <option>APR</option>
            <option>MAY</option>
            <option>JUN</option>
            <option>JUL</option>
            <option>AUG</option>
            <option>SEP</option>
            <option>OCT</option>
            <option>NOV</option>
            <option>DEC</option>
        </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    </label>
</form>
```

CSS (Added one style at the end in fiddle):

```
#divWrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8em;
}
```

Comment: It would be nicer if that could work on Firefox, not sure about IE.

Comment: Oops. Didn't cross browser test that. Thought it was all standard stuff.  Just left work. I'll update it later to work across browsers.

Comment: I've seen this workaround and unfortunately I'm pretty sure it's impossible to work cross browser. It's a sad thing. I don't know why they couldn't just make an event so you could trigger the select box to open. Seems rudimentary, but unfortunately they didn't. I'm all for your attempt though @AtheistP3ace. God speed.

Comment: @zfrisch ah ok. Well I'll give it a shot anyway! Thanks! Update later on if I could or not.

Comment: Yea sorry, I was unable to make this work outside of chrome. Even using the non deprecated new event apis. I can get it to select the dropdown and you can navigate with the keyboard as if it was open in other browsers but it just doesn't "open" like it does in chrome. Seems slightly insane to me that at this day in age there is no way to programmatically do this across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about faking it? You could make the `<select>` element's background transparent and position a button behind it. My example solution doesn't look as pretty as your fiddle did, but it works as a demonstration.

```css
.custom-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: silver;
}

/* Button */
.custom-dropdown::before {
    display: block;
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 30px; /* Same as padding on select */
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 1; /* Position behind */
    text-align: center;
}

.custom-dropdown__select {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2; /* Position in front */
    width: 95px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px; /* Button width */
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <label for="month">
        Choose Month<br/>
        <span class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--silver">
            <select id="month" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--silver">
                <option>JAN</option>
                <option>FEB</option>
                <option>MAR</option>
                <option>APR</option>
                <option>MAY</option>
                <option>JUN</option>
                <option>JUL</option>
                <option>AUG</option>
                <option>SEP</option>
                <option>OCT</option>
                <option>NOV</option>
                <option>DEC</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: thx, but i still need the space between the arrow toggle and the options. Using your method i can hack it with a border-left on the `.custom-dropdown::before` element if the background is a solid color, but if I have an image/multicolored background behind the dropdown it won't work.

Comment: Actually, if you're going the border-left route, you could use a transparent border

Comment: Ah, you're right. The border wouldn't work, sorry. I'm multitasking at the moment.
This space needs to be more than just graphical whitespace and can't be clicked? If you need just a little space, you could cover up that portion with another div positioned over top and fake the background color in yet another pseudo element like the button.

Comment: no worries, i appreciate the help :) yeah, area shouldn't be clickable. i'll look into your suggestion.